# StreamWriter not writing all characters

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have this bit of code run when people close the game to save all their currently selected pets (this is for school don't worry about how I named it "Squirtle", no copyright problems here). The code in question is:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@"..\..\pets.txt"))
{
    sw.AutoFlush = true;
    foreach (Pet p in petList)
    {
        sw.Write(p.PetID + ' ');
        sw.Write(p.Name + ' ');
        sw.Write(p.HP + ' ');
        sw.Write(p.Type + ' ');
        sw.Write(p.Level + ' '  );
        sw.Write(p.Rarity + ' ');
        sw.WriteLine(p.Speed);                               
    }
}
```

the commas were spaces and I just added the autoflush to try and fix the problem, but basically no matter how many times I run it, the first two, next two, and last 3 pieces of data have no spaces between them, example: 32SQUIRTLE 77AQUATIC 41930. this happens every time I run it and am wondering if anyone knows of why it's doing this? I can use any delimiter also if space and comma are notorious with StreamWriter or something.

Comment: if you replace `' '` with `" "` does it fix your problem?

Comment: I'm just looking at it after the stream writer runs and it looks like that, I'm gonna try double quotes and see if it fixes it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are doing `Int + Char`, The overload for this operation would results in `Int + (int) Char` which is casting the space into its Unicode code point and doing arithmetic operation

What you want to do is `p.PetID.ToString() + " "`

Comment: Thats what I was thinking too, but was not confident in the answer enough to post.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I actually debugged one issue like this before so im 100% sure that's the case :D

Comment: thanks man I'll give it good answer in like 10 minutes when it lets me